# How to create a composite datetime with fixed date + random time interval in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, datetime, utility

I'm new to Postgresql, and I'm looking for a way to return a composite datetime, built with a fixed date, and a random time, defined as an interval.

An example:

```
2020-12-02 10:00:00
2020-12-02 10:10:20
2020-12-02 08:25:23
2020-12-02 09:12:11
```

As you can see the date is fixed, and time remains between 08:00:00 and 10:30:00.

Do you know how to replicate this behaviour using a Postgresql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
select '2020-12-02 08:00:00'::timestamp + random() * interval '2 hour 30 minute'
```

Or, for the current date, you could express this as:

```
select current_date + interval '08:00:00' + random() * interval '02:30'
```

Note that these illustrate two different ways of expressing an interval with 2 hours and 30 minutes (and not even giving `interval '150 minute'` as an example).

Comment: Hi Gordon, your second example is interesting. So using current_date + interval '<time>' is equivalent to my original code? I have to study the `interval` keyword a little more, sound like it can do more than I thought. Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 1):

As a total newbie of Postgresql (but with some experience in general SQL), and reading some posts here, I've found an easy way to get it done:

```sql
SELECT

 CURRENT_DATE + time '08:00:00' + 

 (random() * interval '3 hours')::time

AS date_wrandom_t

FROM generate_series(1, 50)
```

`generate_series` *its here only to demonstrate some results, you can omit it and get a single result.*

**What it does:**

1. Takes the current date (today)
2. Defines the starting time (min value)
3. Generate a random interval of 3 hours - (tested with `SELECT (random() * interval '3 hours')::time`)
4. Add the result to the minimum time (08:00:00)

Maybe it's not the best solution, but I like it as it's based on a simple syntax, easy to remember.

I wish to find some time to study this DBMS, it seems really powerful.

Any addition/suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Yet another way: `select current_date + make_interval(hours => 8, secs => random() * 3*60*60);`